# Why when using relative positioning values with unordered list I'm able to scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I'm a little bit confused on why the page allows me to scroll horizontally even if there's nothing there. I started to see this when I changed my lists to relative positioning. I don't understand why that blank space. However, this does not happen when I use absolute positioning, but I want to use relative positioning. Please, what is happening? The problem is in the list within "div_footer". Here's my HTML code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">

        </head>

        <body>

            <div class="body_container">
                    <div id="div_header">
                        <div id="nav">
                            <div id="nav_wrapper">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Example</a></li><li>
                                    <a href="#">Example</a></li><li>
                                    <a href="#">Example</a></li><li>
                                    <a href="#">Social <img src="seta.gif" id="seta"/></a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Google+</a></li><li>
                                            <a href="#">Facebook</a></li><li>
                                            <a href="#">Twitter</a></li><li>
                                            <a href="#">Tumblr</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="div_leftBar">
                        <ul id="ul_leftBar">
                            <a href="">
                                <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="">
                                <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="">
                                <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="">
                                <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="">
                                <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="">
                                <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="">
                                <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="">
                                <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="">
                                <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</li>
                            </a>
                        </ul>   
                    </div>

                    <div id="div_rightBar">
                    </div>

                    <div id="div_content">

                    </div>

                    <div id="div_footer">
                        <div id="footer_container">
                            <ul id="footer_col1">
                                <h4>Example:</h4>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul id="footer_col2">
                                <h4>Example:</h4>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul id="footer_col3">
                                <h4>Lorem Ipsum Dolor:</h4> 
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul id="footer_col4">
                                <h4>Example:</h4>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Example</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
</html>
```

And here's my CSS code:

```
    body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#ffcc66;
    font-size:18px; 

}
.body_container {
    position: relative;
    height:600px;

}

#div_header {
    background-color:#0000ff;
    width:100%;
    height:40%;
    padding:0px;
    margin-bottom:3%;
}


#nav{
    background-color: #222;
    position:relative;
    top:79%;
}


#nav_wrapper{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;

}


#nav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;

}

#nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px;
}

#nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #333;

}

#nav ul li a,visited{
    color: #ccc;
    display:block;

    text-decoration:none;

}

#nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}


#nav ul ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:51px;
    left:271px;
    background-color: #333;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;
    border:5px solid #222;
    border-top:0;
    min-width:200px;

}

#nav ul ul li{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#nav ul ul li a, visited{
    color: #ccc;
}

#nav ul ul li a:hover{
    color:#899;
}
#seta{
    position:relative;
    top:2px;

}

#div_leftBar{
    background-color:orange;
    width:12%;
    height:60%;
    position:absolute;
}


#ul_leftBar{
    position:relative;
    left:10%;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:15% 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:16px;
}

#ul_leftBar li{
    padding:0 0 10% 0;

}

#div_rightBar{
    background-color:red;
    width:14%;
    height:60%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;      
}

#div_content{
    background-color:green;
    width:65%;
    height:120%;
    position:relative;
    left:17%;       
}


#div_footer{
    background-color:#ffff00;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    height:35%;
    margin:5% 0 0 0;
    padding:0px;    
}

#div_footer ul li {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#footer_col1{
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#footer_col2{
    position:relative;
    top:-84%;
    right:-20%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#footer_col3{
    position:relative;
    top:-168%;
    right:-40%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#footer_col4{
    position:relative;
    top:-252%;
    right:-60%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#footer_container{
    background-color:#333;
    width:70%;
    height:75%;
    position:relative;
    left:15%;
    top:13%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle of this code: http://jsfiddle.net/KsAZ8/542/

Comment: It's occurring due to the CSS of your footer. Comment it out and you will see this. To be more specific, it is the positioning of the elements inside of it through the use of right:-(PERCENTAGE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Issue

The 'ul' objects in your footer are blocks. That means they always have an invisible width:100%, to match their parent container's width. If the parent is 800px, each 'ul' is normally 800px too.

When you shift one to the right, their width doesn't change. They're still huge, but taking up extra space on the right.

You can see it clearly when highlighting the 'ul's with borders:
http://jsfiddle.net/KsAZ8/543/

### Solutions

Try a different technique.

**Technique #1: Use your current position:relative technique**, but also give each 'ul' a width, perhaps 25%.

This removes the horizontal scrollbar problem. But you have lingering issues: it looks bad on narrow screens ('ul's start to overlap) and in Firefox (I don't see this in Chrome or IE) there's a massive invisible ghost below them: http://jsfiddle.net/KsAZ8/544/

**Technique #2: Use inline-blocks**
Remove all your #footer_col1, 2, 3, 4 lines, and add this CSS:

```
#div_footer ul {
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;    
}
```

I use 24% to make up for rounding errors, and with this background, you won't even notice the difference in 1%.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KsAZ8/553/

**Technique #3: Use Absolute Positioning**
Only works if it's a fixed height.

Replace each appropriate CSS block with the following:

```
#div_footer ul {
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    height: 8em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;    
}
#footer_col2 {
    left: 25%;
}
#footer_col3 {
    left: 50%;
}
#footer_col4 {
    left: 75%;
}           
#footer_container{
    background-color:#333;
    width:70%;
    height:8em;
    position:relative;
    left:15%;
    top:13%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KsAZ8/554/

**Technique #4: Use Floats and Clearfixes**

Remove all your #footer_col1, 2, 3, 4 lines, and add this CSS:

```
#div_footer ul {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;    
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Also add this after your 'ul's:

```
<div class="cf"></div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KsAZ8/556/

Why did I list so many? Because there's a lot of techniques in a developer's toolbox, and to succeed, you should know as many as possible. Floats do not work in every situation, but in your case, they're just what you need. Or inline-blocks. Either of those will work for you. Position: absolute is a little picky and easily causes problems.

Comment: I have a little question on the Technique #4. I didn't quite understand what you did, why did you use " " after content, how does that work?

Comment: While it doesn't actively do anything, its mere presence prevents a bug in Opera that normally puts unnecessary space around this clearfix. The nitty gritty on this clearfix can be found on Nicolas Gallagher's site: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: Now that it's been a day, I just realized a flaw in my code. 1. You don't need a clearfix at all-- your footer has a fixed height, and there's nothing underneath it, which erases the two benefits of clearfixes (corrects heights of parents with floated elements, and clear floats for later content). 2. Even if you did, clearfixes should be applied to the parent. So you'd remove that extra <div> and put class="cf" on footer_container instead. 3. You could keep the <div> and add clear:both to it instead. Details on this and more about floats/clearfixes can be found at: http://tinyurl.com/6cl9mm

Comment: I see that technique #4 works now, but I made it work by using techniques #1 and #2, thanks for writing this technique, I might use it in the fututre again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your fix. You were trying to pretty much absolutely position all of the content in your footer. I have rearranged your CSS to the following for the footer section:

**CSS**

```
#div_footer {
    background-color:#ffff00;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    height:35%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin:5% 0 0 0;
    padding:0px;
}
#div_footer ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
}
#footer_col1 {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#footer_col2 {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#footer_col3 {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#footer_col4 {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#footer_container {
    background-color:#333;
    width:70%;
    height:75%;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    left:15%;
    top:13%;
}
```

I took out the `right:-20%;` and so forth on each footer column because it was the culprit causing your page to be wider than it actually was. All I did was add floats to help keep the elements in the footer.

**[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsAZ8/547/)**